# Timers from ASP.NET to MVC Razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress

I'm moving an app from ASP.NET/C# to MVC and I have some Timers `<asp:Timer>`
I'm trying to find exactly the same tool for MVC (`Html5` or `DevExpress`) but seems like there is not or at least my intellisense doesn't show it.

Anyone knows about it and can post the squema of it?

Comment: You need to use Javascript.

Comment: What do you use the timers for?

Comment: I use the timers to refresh the view, so it can be 1 minute, 5, 10, 15 or None. After that time, the page automatically refreshes.
@spender I mean, the representation of how to declare a html timer and which fields are required and what each one means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use Javascript yourself.

Take a look at [window.setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) or one of the many jQuery timers.

Comment: I know I can with Js, I was just wondering if there was a solution in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Another option, that doesn't involve javascript is the [HTML META](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp) tag.

example:
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">`

content is specified in *seconds*.  META elements live within the HEAD element.